# How to edit data from a database using QLineEdit or Something else

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

I have QTableView filled with data from a database,I made it to on one click mark some row but now I have a problem...

I want to open a new window with a double click, which will contain QLineEdit with already existing data from the database and if necessary, change them and record them to the database? How can i do it?
EDIT:
I succeeded to print data from database but I have not yet displayed as a result in a new window in QLineEdit

code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QTableView, QAbstractItemView,QLabel,QLineEdit,QTextEdit,QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtSql,QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
import sqlite3 as mdb


class sqlite_conect(object):
    def sqlite_conect(self, find_text, find_function):
        self.connection = mdb.connect('imenik.db')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.find_text1 = "%" + find_text + "%"

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("SQLITE3");

        ok = db.open()



def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("imenik.db")
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Cannot open database",
                    "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                     "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                     "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                     "to build it.\n\n"
                     "Click Cancel to exit.", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False
    return True


class Glavni_prozor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Glavni_prozor, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(1024, 768)
        self.edit_window = edit_window(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tabelaEditovanje = QTableView()
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 200)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.doubleClicked.connect(self.select_id)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.doubleClicked.connect(self.prikazi_drugi)


        layout.addWidget(self.tabelaEditovanje)
        # pravi promjenjivu za pretragu baze podataka
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
        self.model.setQuery("SELECT Lokacija,Kancelarija,Prezime,Ime,Telefon,Lokal,Fax,Oblast FROM telImenik")
        # upisuje rezultate pretrage baze u self.tableView
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setModel(self.model)
        # odredjuje sirinu kolona u self.tableView-u prva kolona je 0-nulta,id nema potrebe dodavati jer ga sam odredjuje
        for i, width in enumerate([150, 65, 100, 80, 90, 40, 80, 340]):
            self.tabelaEditovanje.setColumnWidth(i, width)

    def prikazi_drugi(self):
        self.edit_window.show()

    def close(self):
        self.edit_window.close()
        super(Glavni_prozor, self).close()

    def select_id(self,index):
        id_read=index.row()+1
        print(id_read)
        konekcija = sqlite_conect()
        konekcija.sqlite_conect("", "")
        konekcija.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM telImenik WHERE id= '%s'" % (id_read))
        row = konekcija.cursor.fetchone()
        print(row)
class edit_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(edit_window, self).__init__()
        edit_window.setWindowTitle(self,'Izmjena podataka postojećeg korisnika')
        self.setFixedSize(500, 400)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 20, 421, 231))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.groupBox.setTitle('Edit Contact')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 391, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText('Izmjena postojećeg kontakta')
        self.le_prezime = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_prezime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 150, 20))
        self.le_prezime.setObjectName("le_prezime")
        self.le_ime = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_ime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 160, 150, 20))
        self.le_ime.setObjectName("le_ime")
        self.le_telefon = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_telefon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 190, 150, 20))
        self.le_telefon.setObjectName("le_telefon")
        self.le_lokal = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_lokal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 220, 150, 20))
        self.le_lokal.setObjectName("le_lokal")
        self.le_fax = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_fax.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 250, 150, 20))
        self.le_fax.setObjectName("le_fax")
        self.le_oblast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_oblast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 280, 150, 20))
        self.le_oblast.setObjectName("le_oblast")
        self.lbl_prezime = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_prezime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 130, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_prezime.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_prezime.setObjectName("lbl_prezime")
        self.lbl_prezime.setText('Prezime')
        self.lbl_ime = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_ime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_ime.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_ime.setObjectName("lbl_ime")
        self.lbl_ime.setText('Ime')
        self.lbl_telefon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_telefon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 190, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_telefon.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_telefon.setObjectName("lbl_telefon")
        self.lbl_telefon.setText('Telefon')
        self.lbl_lokal = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_lokal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 220, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_lokal.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_lokal.setObjectName("lbl_lokal")
        self.lbl_lokal.setText('Lokal')
        self.lbl_fax = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_fax.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_fax.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_fax.setObjectName("lbl_fax")
        self.lbl_fax.setText('Fax')
        self.lbl_oblast = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_oblast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_oblast.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_oblast.setObjectName("lbl_oblast")
        self.lbl_oblast.setText('Oblast')
        self.btn_save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.btn_save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 340, 80, 25))
        self.btn_save.setObjectName("btn_save")
        self.btn_save.setText('Snimi izmjene')
        self.btn_cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.btn_cancel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 340, 80, 25))
        self.btn_cancel.setObjectName("btn_cancel")
        self.btn_cancel.setText('Odustani')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)

    def select_id(self,index):
        id_read=index()+1
        print(id_read)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)
    mw = Glavni_prozor()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: According to the history I see that you have added irrelevant things, I would expect that you have advanced something. What have you tried? What have you advanced since yesterday?

Comment: I'm trying to do something in my free time that I have very little, sometimes I go for 20 days without looking at the code ... If you want to help then thank you if you will not thank again! There is no need for such comments

Comment: The comments are not to offend, the comments are to point out things that you could improve and thus make your questions attractive instead of just editing irrelevant things. It would be great if you added your progress. :-)Finally I recommend reading [ask] and use some of those tips to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QTableView, QAbstractItemView,QLabel,QLineEdit,QTextEdit,QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtSql,QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
import sqlite3 as mdb


class sqlite_conect(object):
    def sqlite_conect(self, find_text, find_function):
        self.connection = mdb.connect('imenik.db')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.find_text1 = "%" + find_text + "%"

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("SQLITE3");

        ok = db.open()


def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("imenik.db")
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Cannot open database",
                    "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                     "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                     "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                     "to build it.\n\n"
                     "Click Cancel to exit.", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False
    return True


class Glavni_prozor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Glavni_prozor, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(1024, 768)

        self.edit_window = edit_window(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tabelaEditovanje = QTableView()
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 200)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.doubleClicked.connect(self.select_id)
        self.tabelaEditovanje.doubleClicked.connect(self.prikazi_drugi)

        layout.addWidget(self.tabelaEditovanje)

        # pravi promjenjivu za pretragu baze podataka
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()


## ---
        ##self.model.setQuery("SELECT Lokacija,Kancelarija,Prezime,Ime,Telefon,Lokal,Fax,Oblast FROM telImenik")
# +++ id, !!!
        self.model.setQuery("""SELECT 
                                   id,                
                                   Lokacija,
                                   Kancelarija,
                                   Prezime,
                                   Ime,
                                   Telefon,
                                   Lokal,
                                   Fax,
                                   Oblast 
                               FROM telImenik""")        

        # upisuje rezultate pretrage baze u self.tableView
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setModel(self.model)


# ---
        ## odredjuje sirinu kolona u self.tableView-u prva kolona je 0-nulta,id nema potrebe dodavati jer ga sam odredjuje
        ##for i, width in enumerate([150, 65, 100, 80, 90, 40, 80, 340]):
        ##    self.tabelaEditovanje.setColumnWidth(i, width)

# +++
        for i, width in enumerate([10, 150, 65, 100, 80, 90, 40, 80, 340]):
            self.tabelaEditovanje.setColumnWidth(i, width)
        # Если hide True/верно, данный столбец будет скрыт; в противном случае это будет показано.
        self.tabelaEditovanje.setColumnHidden(0, True) # id не показываем!!!    


    def prikazi_drugi(self):
        self.edit_window.show()

    def close(self):
        self.edit_window.close()
        super(Glavni_prozor, self).close()

# --- +++        
    def select_id(self, index):

# ---        id_read=index.row()+1
# ---        print(id_read)
# ---        konekcija = sqlite_conect()
# ---        konekcija.sqlite_conect("", "")
# ---        konekcija.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM telImenik WHERE id= '%s'" % (id_read))
# ---        row = konekcija.cursor.fetchone()
# ---        print(row)

# +++
        row = index.row()
        self.id_db  = self.model.record(row).value("id")
        print("row->`{}`, id_db->`{}`".format(row, self.id_db))

        self.edit_window.le_prezime.setText(self.model.record(row).value("Prezime"))
        self.edit_window.le_ime.setText(    self.model.record(row).value("Ime"))
        self.edit_window.le_telefon.setText(self.model.record(row).value("Telefon"))
        self.edit_window.le_lokal.setText(  self.model.record(row).value("Lokal"))
        self.edit_window.le_fax.setText(    self.model.record(row).value("Fax"))     
        self.edit_window.le_oblast.setText( self.model.record(row).value("Oblast"))

# +++
    def clickedBtnSave(self):
        prezime = self.edit_window.le_prezime.text()
        ime     = self.edit_window.le_ime.text()
        telefon = self.edit_window.le_telefon.text()
        lokal   = self.edit_window.le_lokal.text()
        fax     = self.edit_window.le_fax.text()
        oblast  = self.edit_window.le_oblast.text()

        self.editDb(self.id_db, prezime, ime, telefon, lokal, fax, oblast)

# +++        
    def editDb(self, id_db, prezime, ime, telefon, lokal, fax, oblast):
        self.edit_window.hide()
        q = QtSql.QSqlQuery(""" UPDATE telImenik 
                                   SET Prezime = '{}',
                                       Ime     = '{}',
                                       Telefon = '{}',
                                       Lokal   = '{}',
                                       Fax     = '{}',
                                       Oblast  = '{}'
                                 WHERE id =  '{}'
                            """.format(prezime, ime, telefon, lokal, fax, oblast, id_db))

        result = q.exec_()
        if result:
            self.model.query().exec_()
            print("Ok!!!")
        else:
            print("Error ->", self.model.query().lastError().text())
        return result  

# +++        
    def clickedBtnCancel(self):        
        self.edit_window.hide()


class edit_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(edit_window, self).__init__()

        edit_window.setWindowTitle(self,'Izmjena podataka postojećeg korisnika')
        self.setFixedSize(500, 400)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 20, 421, 231))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.groupBox.setTitle('Edit Contact')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 391, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText('Izmjena postojećeg kontakta')

        self.le_prezime = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_prezime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 150, 20))
        self.le_prezime.setObjectName("le_prezime")
        self.le_ime = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_ime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 160, 150, 20))
        self.le_ime.setObjectName("le_ime")
        self.le_telefon = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_telefon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 190, 150, 20))
        self.le_telefon.setObjectName("le_telefon")
        self.le_lokal = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_lokal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 220, 150, 20))
        self.le_lokal.setObjectName("le_lokal")
        self.le_fax = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_fax.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 250, 150, 20))
        self.le_fax.setObjectName("le_fax")
        self.le_oblast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.le_oblast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 280, 150, 20))
        self.le_oblast.setObjectName("le_oblast")
        self.lbl_prezime = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_prezime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 130, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_prezime.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_prezime.setObjectName("lbl_prezime")
        self.lbl_prezime.setText('Prezime')
        self.lbl_ime = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_ime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_ime.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_ime.setObjectName("lbl_ime")
        self.lbl_ime.setText('Ime')
        self.lbl_telefon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_telefon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 190, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_telefon.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_telefon.setObjectName("lbl_telefon")
        self.lbl_telefon.setText('Telefon')
        self.lbl_lokal = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_lokal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 220, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_lokal.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_lokal.setObjectName("lbl_lokal")
        self.lbl_lokal.setText('Lokal')
        self.lbl_fax = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_fax.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_fax.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_fax.setObjectName("lbl_fax")
        self.lbl_fax.setText('Fax')
        self.lbl_oblast = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.lbl_oblast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 150, 20))
        self.lbl_oblast.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbl_oblast.setObjectName("lbl_oblast")
        self.lbl_oblast.setText('Oblast')


# ---    self.btn_save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
# +++
        self.btn_save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox, clicked=parent.clickedBtnSave)

        self.btn_save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 340, 80, 25))
        self.btn_save.setObjectName("btn_save")
        self.btn_save.setText('Snimi izmjene')

# ---    self.btn_cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
# +++
        self.btn_cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox, clicked=parent.clickedBtnCancel)

        self.btn_cancel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 340, 80, 25))
        self.btn_cancel.setObjectName("btn_cancel")
        self.btn_cancel.setText('Odustani')

        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)

    def select_id(self,index):
        id_read=index()+1
        print(id_read)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)
    mw = Glavni_prozor()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot